# Count 3 hours overtime with in a given date time window

Tags: mysql

I have to implement an access control system for a company, that will be able to report the access of each employee in a specific area of the building in order to provide a report.
One of the requirements is to provide a list of the employees with more than 3 hours overtime with in a given date time window.

The table schema of the table that holds the required information is the following.
`ACTION` states if the employee entered or left a specific level of the building. The rest are the time, the employee and the level.

```
create table access_action
(
    ID          bigint auto_increment primary key,
    ACTION      int      null,
    TIMESTAMP   datetime null,
    level_id    bigint   null,
    employee_id bigint   null,
    constraint FK_access_action_employee_id
        foreign key (employee_id) references employee (ID),
    constraint FK_access_action_level_id
        foreign key (level_id) references level (ID)
);
```

a sample result set

```
ID  ACTION      TIMESTAMP       EMPLOYEE_ID
1   IN  2017-05-10 09:28:00 3   9
2   IN  2017-04-24 07:49:00 3   8
3   IN  2017-02-27 07:08:00 1   9
4   IN  2017-04-26 06:15:00 1   25
5   IN  2017-02-02 09:37:00 3   24
6   OUT 2017-05-29 08:03:00 3   7
7   IN  2017-04-25 07:07:00 1   1
8   IN  2017-01-09 08:54:00 3   8
9   IN  2017-05-12 07:57:00 2   1
10  OUT 2017-02-09 08:03:00 3   30
11  IN  2017-03-09 08:56:00 3   30
12  OUT 2017-02-03 11:26:00 3   5
```

I believe I know how I can estimate the overtime considering the sum up of the time each employee spent inside the premises of the building which will give the total hours. But I only can imagine how I could do it in the application layer.

Is there a way I can estimate the overtimes purely with SQL?

**EDIT**

According to the comments there must be a strict sequence among the enter - leave actions therefore a created the following [data set](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=51c2e36ca895d4da92e487670b1351ba).

Comment: Considering that empploee id 9 enters two times and never leaves , you should be more careful choosing  your data,. More importantly which mysql version are you using?

Comment: @nbk You are right. `version 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`

Comment: as you can see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b9357e0ed529cb02bca9279d12c784e7  there is no chance to even tell the time the were at the building at one level. Besides when is overtime after 8 hours with breaks.

Comment: @nbk as I wrote this is only a sample, I can provide the full data set but it would be massive and even then some inconsistent data might appear. Lets imagine there is a check mechanism that doesn't allow an employee to enter or leave the building without first checking his card.

Comment: @nbk my guess is you have to count the time that an employee spent INside the premises regardless the level and if it's above 8 hours then it's overtime .

Comment: Your task can be easily solved when IN-OUT rotation is ensured (no lost actions), and it is unsolvable if not.

Comment: @Akina since it is so easy can you please provide a query or at least a hint on how to start? A reference or a related example would be also beneficial. Would it make it easier if I provide a correct set of data (no actions lost)?

Comment: *Would it make it easier if I provide a correct set of data (no actions lost)?* I'd say it is compulsory. The best way - in a fiddle form.

Comment: *or at least a hint on how to start?* Use 2 table copies joined by employee - 1st for IN and 2nd for OUT. For each IN time its according OUT time is minimal time which is above.

Comment: @Akina I'd like to thank you for the hint, I believe it led me to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Akina s comment, I created two sets one for the IN actions and another for the OUT, which I joined them and subtract the time spent inside the premises. Therefore I can calculate the total working hours for each employee in any particular day.

I came up with the following query.

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @row_number1 = 0;

select SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(abb.overtimes) ) ) overtimes, employee_id
from
    (select TIMEDIFF(ab.working_time,'08:00:00') overtimes, ab.employee_id from
        (select SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(aaaa.timespent) ) working_time, accessDate, aaaa.employee_id
            from
            (select aaa.OUTtime as OUTtime, aaa.INtime, TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF(OUTtime, INtime) ) as timespent, DATE(OUTtime) as accessDate, aaa.level_id, aaa.employee_id
             from
                 (select aa1.TIMESTAMP as OUTtime, aa2.TIMESTAMP as INtime, aa1.level_id, aa1.employee_id
                  from (select
                            (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) row_num,
                            a1.TIMESTAMP, a1.employee_id, a1.level_id
                        from access_action a1
                        where a1.ACTION = 'OUT'
                        order by employee_id asc, TIMESTAMP desc) aa1
                           INNER JOIN
                       (select
                            (@row_number1:=@row_number1 + 1) row_num,
                            a2.TIMESTAMP, a2.employee_id, a2.level_id
                        from access_action a2
                        where a2.ACTION = 'IN'
                        order by employee_id asc, TIMESTAMP desc) aa2
                       ON aa1.row_num = aa2.row_num) aaa) aaaa
        group by accessDate, aaaa.employee_id
        having accessDate >= '2017-05-26' and accessDate <= '2017-05-30'
        AND working_time > '08:00:00') ab) abb
group by employee_id
having overtimes > '03:00:00';
```

Performing the query in the [data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=546a842fbe38a4d76d45d364364ff2c7) the result is the following.

```
overtimes   employee_id
03:50:00    4
```